# issue when trying to implement chartjs-plugin-datalabels in vue-chartjs charts

Tags: chart.js, vue-chartjs

I am attempting to install chartjs-plugin-datalabels. I am using vue-chartjs and need to include the plugin for datalabels (if anyone can recommend anything else itd be much appreciated.)

my current versions for everything is
chart.js@3.8.0
vue-chartjs@3.5.1
vue@2.6.14

he is my code for reference:

```
<script>
import { Bar, mixins } from "vue-chartjs";
import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
export default {
  extends: Bar,
  props: ["options"],
  mixins: [mixins.reactiveProp],
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
  },
};
</script>
```

My issue:
after downloading chartjs-plugin-datalabels, none of my charts work anymore. I'm now getting these errors when I load my page:

[image]

I have a feeling the issue is likely due to the versions and version requirements not aligning at the moment. Is there any way to solve this?

Additionally, If there is an alternative way to have something similar to datalabels that does not require plugins Id must prefer avoiding the headache of this plugin.
my required look is to have a doughnut chart with 2 datasets where one is presented as a number and the other as a %
i.e:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using incopatible versions of chart.js and vue-chart.js.

Vue-chart.js v3 only works with Chart.js V2.

For Chart.js V3 you need vue-chart.js V4.

Make sure that if you decide to update vue-chart.js to V4 to import everything from the `'vue-chartjs/legacy'` package since you are using Vue V2 and not V3.

So then your import will look like this:

```js
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs/legacy'
```